# Filter CSV File with Pandas/Python

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I have a CSV file, I wanted to filter it where I keep just rows where I have values in row "d" bigger then 0.

**File:**

```
  index  value    d
0    975  25.35   5
1    976  26.28   4
2    977  26.24   1
3    978  25.76   0
4    979  26.08   0
```

I used pandas to do that, but It didn't work out:

```
df = pd.read_csv("ThisFileL.csv")
df = df[(df["d"]>0)]
```

I used other approach as well, but it's too long to process a file of 600mb.

```
with open("ThisFileL.csv", 'rb') as source:
    writer = csv.writer(source)
    for line in source:
        if line.d > 0 :
              writer.writerow(headers)
```

Comment: Your code should work, what version of Pandas are you using?

Comment: Note that your code will modify the dataframe, but not the csv file. If you want to save the filtered data to a file, you need to call `df.to_csv('filtered.csv')`

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, no pandas solution, but this is the kind of task where basic Unix tools cannot be beaten. If you use Windows you can do the same with Cygwin:

```
$ awk '{if ($4 > 0) print $0}' t.csv 
  0    975  25.35   5
  1    976  26.28   4
  2    977  26.24   1
```

You can filter the data in your desired way, save it to another file, and then read in using pandas:

```
$ awk '{if ($4 > 0) print $0}' t.csv >filtered.csv
```

Comment: this is really cool; i would recommend to extend it to `($4 > 0 || NR == 1)` in order to keep the header line;

Comment: I happen to have a 9-GB csv file that I need to filter depending on one of its column's value (a numeric value). Do you think that `awk` is also faster than `pandas` here too?